# .htaccess: how to convert this URL?

Tags: .htaccess

Using .htaccess, how do I convert this URL

http://engine.searchr.us/web-search.phtml?search=SEARCHED+TEXT

to

http://engine.searchr.us/web-search/search/SEARCHED-TEXT.html

?

and I should place the .htaccess in the engine folder right?

Comment: Do you want to redirect `/web-search/search/QUERY.html` (visible to the user) to `/web-search.phtml` (internal redirect) or the reverse?

Comment: I'm looking for something like this : /web-search/search/QUERY.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, with just the standard Apache modules. `mod_rewrite` might be closest, but it can't process the QUERY_STRING. So you'll have to implement some kind of server-side code (CGI, PHP, mod_python) to implement the redirect. I'd personally use a Python-implemented CGI script.

Comment: Not true. `mod_rewrite` can most certainly process the query string, but you need a `RewriteCond` to do it, not just a `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

Making the Query String Part of the Path

Take a URL of the form http://example.com/path?var=val and transform it into http://example.com/path/var/val. Note that this particular example will work only for a single var=val pair containing only letters, numbers, and the underscore character.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^/path /path/%1/%2?
```

You'll have to do something about the spaces/pluses in the search term. I would really recommend implementing some kind of CGI script as Martin suggested, but I think you could keep rewriting the QUERY_STRING portion until all spaces are dashes as well (you're going to have to figure that out on your own though!)

Good luck!

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html